# renderDataTable in Shiny not rendering output correctly

Tags: r, datatables, shiny, dt

I am executing a very minimal `renderDataTable` example posted on the DT github page below
http://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
      iris, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)
    )
  }
)
```

However, the output I am seeing after executing this code is garbage, column names listed in a single line without space.

[image]

I tried this after uninstalling my DT packages and reinstalling again

```
devtools::install_github('rstudio/DT')
```

Nothing changed, still the same results. I don't understand why  DT::renderDataTable() is not working. Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.?

-------------Update----------------

I started noticing this issue after I started building some shinyapps using Flexdashboard. Before installing Flexdashboard package everything was working as usual and there was no problem, after installing Flexdashboard i noticed this issue with datatables while using `renderDataTable` function

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your output.  Do you have a stylesheet loaded somewhere?

Comment: Did you see this result in the RStudio viewer, or your web browser?

Comment: Is `htmlwidgets` is up to date?

Comment: renderDataTable doesn't call `datatable` on the output, you need it to be: `output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
      {datatable(iris)}, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)
    )`

Comment: @Benjamin, I am not using any stylesheets, just the same example on the github/DT website

Comment: @alistaire, when i reinstalled htmlwidgets from `devtools::install_github('ramnathv/htmlwidgets')`, it worked but only once, when i ran the same code again this issue reappeared.

Comment: @Shape, I have another shiny example, `DT::datatable(diamonds2[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE],
                escape = FALSE,
                callback = JS(
                  'table.on("click.dt","tr",function() {
                                               var data1 =table.row(this).data();
                                               console.log(data1);
                                         })'
                ))` which is similar to what you described above, but i am still seeing the same issue when I execute this example. :(

Comment: @warmoverflow, either in RStudio Viewer or browser still the same issue

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. It could be a configuration issue. Please post the `sessionInfo()` output.

Comment: @MikeWise, based on jj allaire suggestion after adding `options(DT.fillContainer = FALSE)
options(DT.autoHideNavigation = FALSE)` in Shiny, everything seems to work normally. Looks like this is an issue with `Flexdashboard`

Comment: Well, write it up and post it as an answer I guess. Might help someone someday.

Answer (score 3):

This issue is about not being able to see the contents of a datatables while using the `renderdatatable` function.

This happens if the users using `renderdatatable` function in their regular shiny app switch from shiny to `flexdashboard` try to run `flexdashboard` apps that use `renderdatatable` function and switch back to shiny.

The `flexdashboard` library 1) will not render the datatables through the `renderdatatable` function, at least as of today it did not 2) Further the `flexdashboard` library corrupts some of the functionalities within the datatables package and when the user tries to switch back to regular Shiny from  `flexdashboard` , the user may find that the `renderdatatable` function that worked earlier might not render the datatables accurately.

According to JJ Allaire, the solution is to add these two lines in your shiny

```
 options(DT.fillContainer = FALSE) 
 options(DT.autoHideNavigation = FALSE)
```

This will clean up all the hooks `flexdashboard` creates within the `datatable` package and datatable should render normally like before in Shiny.